# netbeans shortcut for typing custom character or word

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Is it possible in Netbeans 8, to assign a shortcut key for typing specific character or word? (for example `&zwnj;`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use create macro (Options|Editor|Macros) or create a code template (Options|Editor|Code templates).